# Load @Html.Action using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

On my dashboard I have the following div which works fine and when the page is loaded the action return a view

```
    <div id="result1" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
        @Html.Action("index", "Gauge1", new { p1 = 2025, p2 = 8, p3 = 101 })                         
    </div>
```

How can I load the view generated from the `@Html.Action` into the `<div id = "result1"` when `(document).ready` in JQuery?

I tried this but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result1').load(@(Html.Action("index", "Gauge1", new { p1 = 2025, p2 = 8, p3 = 101 })));
       }); 
</script>

<div id="result1" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
</div>
```

Comment: You need `Url.Action`

Comment: @Satpal, Thanks for your assistance, Everyone is suggesting using `Url.Action` but maybe because I want to return a View, `Url` does not seem to work!!

Comment: @Erwin1, do you have errors in console ?

Comment: @Erwin1, I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: As a guideline I recommend you avoid injecting into Javascript code directly in views. This stops you being able to use TypeScript and separate JS files (and therefore most cool debugging options). Inject into a DOM element data attribute and pick that up from your JS file (or worst case inject into a global variable and pickup that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Url.Action` helper method is used to generate urls. It generates a valid url by encoding all parameters.

So, in your example ampersand will be encoded and your url will look like this:

```
/Gauge1/index?p1=2025&amp;p2=8&amp;p3=101
```

In `Razor` every content using a @ block is automatically HTML encoded by Razor.

The `Url.Action` returns just a string so thats why the & gets encoded.

You need to use `@Html.Raw` to prevent the Encode of &.

Please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","Gauge1", new { p1=2025, p2=8,p3=101})))";
     $('#result1').load(url);
</script>

<div id="result1" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome ! Another method is to use this: `var url="@Url.Action("index","Gauge1")?p1=2012&p2=10&p3=101";`

Answer (score 1):

As a guideline I recommend you avoid injecting into Javascript code directly in views. This stops you being able to use TypeScript and separate JS files (and therefore most cool debugging options). Inject into a DOM element data attribute and pick that up from your JS file (or worst case inject into a global variable and pickup that)..

### e.g. add a Url.Action to your DIV (and add a class like `loadme`):

```
<div id="result1" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 loadme" data-url="@(Url.Action("index", "Gauge1", new { p1 = 2025, p2 = 8, p3 = 101 }))">
</div>
```

### Then in script (preferably a separate TS/JS file):

```
$(function(){
    $('.loadme').each(function(){
         var $div = $(this);
         $div.load($div.data('url'));
    })
});
```

This style of attributes and separate code is more like writing plugins/widgets and you can debug your code without effort. The above will support loading any number of divs, whereas the original was hardwired for one.

### Notes:

- `$(function(){...});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready` and the preferred way to do that nowadays,

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to jquery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function `url` from where you get your View.

`Html.Action` helper renders View (it returns html page).

You should use `Url.Action` helper to generate url.

```
$('#result1').load('@(Url.Action("index", 
                      "Gauge1", 
                      new { p1 = 2025, p2 = 8, p3 = 101 }))');
```

Comment: I tried the `Url.` , does not work. I am using `Html.Action` because I want to return a View.

Comment: @Erwin1 check what you get in console (F12 in browser). This code should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result1').load("/Gauge1/index?p1=2025&p2=8&p3=101");
   // OR
    var url = '@Url.Action("index", "Gauge1", new { p1 = 2025, p2 = 8, p3 = 101 })'
    $('#result1').load(url);
});
```

Comment: @Erwin1 try first one or check if you getting any error in Console?